# grepelli issue with autocomplete_search_fields

Tags: django

```
class DemoProvider(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        if self.MidName == None:
            return u'%s, %s' % (self.LastName, self.FirstName)
        else:
            return u'%s, %s %s' % (self.LastName, self.FirstName, self.MidName)
    PracticeName = models.ForeignKey('DemoPractice', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    FirstName = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    MidName = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    LastName = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)

class Billing1500(models.Model):
    Practice = models.ForeignKey('DemoPractice', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Provider = models.ForeignKey('DemoProvider', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    PatiName = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, help_text='Last Name, First Name')
    PatiDOB = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    PatiSex = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    @staticmethod
    def autocomplete_search_fields():
        return ("Provider_icontains", )


@admin.register(Billing1500)
class Billing1500(admin.ModelAdmin):
    raw_id_fields = ('Provider',)
    autocomplete_lookup_fields = {
        'fk': ['Provider'],
    }
    pass
```

i'm trying to have autocomplete search fields in my grapellie admin models, however im getting errors when trying to bind my foreignkeys to my grappelli function. i'm having the following issue

```
ERRORS:
?: (grappelli.E001) Model Core.billing1500 returned bad entries for autocomplete_search_fields: Provider_icontains
        HINT: A QuerySet for {model} could not be constructed. Fix the autocomplete_search_fields on it to return valid lookups.
```

reading the docs it looks like what I have should be correct no?

Comment: What if you use `'Provider__pk'` instead?

Comment: @staticmethod
    def autocomplete_search_fields():
        return ("Provider__pk", )

doesn't give me an error anymore but it doesnt let me search the provider name

Comment: if it has a `name` field or anything similar, you can use `'Provider__name'`.

Comment: its use __str__ so the name should be in the object instaciation

Comment: no, you can not search based on `__str__` at the database side. The `__str__` is how it is *presented* to the user. but you can not search based on the `__str__` since the database is not aware at all that that exists.

Comment: I see. I put 
    @staticmethod
    def autocomplete_search_fields():
        return ("Provider__FirstName", "Provider__MidName", "Provider__LastName", ) however no hits are returning still.